# Transform XML using XSLT - Root Node not present

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have one `XML` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<File>
    <Customer>
        <LastName>MyLastName</LastName>
    </Customer>
    <Cars>
        <Car>
            <Color>Blue</Color>
            <Model>Car2</Model>
            <Year>1988</Year>
            <Speed>250</Speed>
        </Car>
        <Car>
            <Color>Green</Color>
            <Model>Car3</Model>
            <Year>1989</Year>
            <Speed>350</Speed>
        </Car>
    </Cars>
</File>
```

I want to transform this using `XSLT` for have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
    <Purchaser>
        <Name>MyLastName</Name>
    </Purchaser>
    <vehicles>
        <vehicle>
            <vehicleColor>Blue</vehicleColor>
            <vehicleModel>Car2</vehicleModel>
            <vehicleYear>1988</vehicleYear>
            <vehicleSpeed>250</vehicleSpeed>
        </vehicle>
        <vehicle>
            <vehicleColor>Green</vehicleColor>
            <vehicleModel>Car3</vehicleModel>
            <vehicleYear>1989</vehicleYear>
            <vehicleSpeed>350</vehicleSpeed>
        </vehicle>
    </vehicles>
</File>
```

My `XSLT` File :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="utf-8"
            media-type="text/xml"/>


    <xsl:template match="File/Customer">
        <xsl:element name="Purchaser">
            <xsl:element name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="File/Cars">
        <xsl:element name="vehicles">
            <xsl:for-each select="Car">
                <xsl:element name="vehicle">
                    <xsl:element name="vehicleColor">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Color"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="vehicleModel">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Model"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="vehicleYear">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="vehicleSpeed">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Speed"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I have not the root node in my output file. How to do this?

Also, Is this a good way to make the transformation? With several templates stacked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good way to make the transformation? With several templates
>   stacked?

You can use several templates, or one template - in this case, neither method has a distinct advantage or disadvantage against the other. Personally, I would keep it short and simple and stick to one template (mainly because there's only one node you're copying without modification):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/File">
    <File>
        <Purchaser>
            <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="Customer/LastName"/>
            </Name>
        </Purchaser>
        <vehicles>
            <xsl:for-each select="Cars/Car">
                <vehicle>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <xsl:element name="vehicle{name()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </vehicle>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </vehicles>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. `<xsl:element name="vehicle">` is equal to `<vehicle>` ?  Can we write directly the nodes in the xslt file ?

Comment: @Azerty123 As a rule, you should use [literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#literal-result-element), i.e. `<vehicle>`, unless you need to **calculate** the element's name (incl. namespace) - then you would have to use the `xsl:element` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which copies the nodes you don't want to transform like the `File` element and then allows you to add templates doing the transformations like

```
<xsl:template match="Customer">
  <Purchaser>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Purchaser>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LastName">
  <Name>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cars">
  <vehicles>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </vehicles>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Car">
  <vehicle>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </vehicle>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Car/*">
  <xsl:element name="vehicle{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and so on. As you see, I have simply used literal result elements in most places instead of the more verbose `xsl:element` as that is only needed if you need to compute the name and/or namespace at run-time.

Comment: Thanks but I want to define each names of my output nodes like in my `XSLT`. I would to keep my `XSLT` structure

Comment: You asked " Is this a good way to make the transformation?" and I am trying to show you a good, well structured, flexible, extensible and easy way. If you prefer the convoluted way, it is up to you. I don't see why using a literal result element like `<vehicle>...</vehicle>` would not allow you to define the element name, `<xsl:element name="vehicle">...</xsl:element>` achieves exactly the same.

Comment: Ok thank's, How to just define the root node in my XSLT file ?

Comment: The root node is the document node. As for the root element, add the template I have shown first, as I said, it takes care of copying things.